# Redirect all subdomain.mysite.com and mysite.com to www.mysite.com .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying (and failing) to create a 301 redirect condition that sends ANY subdomain a person may enter (e.g. anything.mysite.com) AND mysite.com all to www.mysite.com. Is this even possible? I have successfully gotten one or the other to work, but not both. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's kind of recursive since "www" is also "anything"

Answer (score 1):

You can use in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, Croises. This solution seems to be working just fine!

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@John Charles Smith

You can use either of below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anything\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

**OR**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anything\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Url in `RewriteRule` never begin with `/` in `htaccess`